# Symfony2: problems with highchartsbundle

Tags: symfony, highcharts, composer-php

I have a problem while running

```
composer require ob/highcharts-bundle
```

**Errors:**

> Problem 1
>               zendframework/zend-cache 2.3.3 requires 
>               zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by
>               zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.3.3].
>
> ```
>         zendframework/zend-cache 2.3.3 requires zendframework
>         /zend-stdlib 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.3.3].
>
>         Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.3.3, 2.3.0].
>         zendframework/zend-json 2.3.0 requires zendframework
>         /zend-stdlib 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.3.0].
>
>         ob/highcharts-bundle 1.2 requires zendframework/
>         zend-json 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-json[2.3.0].
>
>         Installation request for ob/highcharts-bundle ~1.2 -> 
>         satisfiable by ob/highcharts-bundle[1.2].
>
>         Installation request for zendframework/zend-cache == 2.3.3.0 
>         -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-cache[2.3.3].
> ```

composer.json

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
    "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "~1.0",
    "lexik/form-filter-bundle": "~3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Any idea for solve?

regards

Comment: add your composer.json here.

Comment: You have 4 options. `1` Remove the zend-cache folder from your vendors and try to update again, it might be because the pdf-bundle has already installed the latest version of zend-cache and won't change it). `2` Use the dev version of the highcharts bundle (`"ob/highcharts-bundle": "1.2.*@dev"`). `3` Use version 2.3.0 of zend-cache (`"zendframework/zend-cache": "2.3.0"`). `4` Fork the highcharts bundle and change the composer.json to be able to use the same zend-cache version as the dev version (`"zendframework/zend-cache": "~2.3"`). There may be others but these would pretty much cover you.